# WCF returning Endpoint not found on live

Tags: .net, json, wcf, web-config, endpoint

I have hosted a WCF service on shared environment which contains two different methods. One is returning the desired output, while the other gives endpoint not found exception, which is my main method to authenticate users.

The scenario is depicted here:

My Iservice.cs is as below

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="GET", UriTemplate = "Data?Id={id}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string GetData(string id);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "Login?InstId={inst}&UserId={user}&pwd={pwd}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string Authenticate(string inst, string user, string pwd);
```

which then authenticates user details through DAL, which is working fine. My web config is as below:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="True" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="True">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>-->
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="True">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFDemo.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://www.ekotri.com/Service1.svc" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" listenUri="/" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WCFDemo.IService1">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://www.ekotri.com" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

GetData is working fine, but Authenticate gives endpoint not found error. It works fine on local IIS though.

Comment: Try to enable help page using [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442(v=vs.110).aspx). Also please check the authentication settings on live and local IIS if there are any differences.

Comment: but i have shared hosting plan, so how to check authentication setting on live server??

Comment: Did you try to change `UriTemplate = "Login?InstId={inst}&UserId={user}&pwd={pwd}"` to something else like `UriTemplate = "helloworld?InstId={inst}&UserId={user}&pwd={pwd}"`. Maybe something is blocking the call or modifying it without you knowing.

Comment: ya i did change authenticate keyword and stuffs like that but its not happening... dont know where am stuck????

Comment: did you try to leave the address="" empty? for me it works like that

Answer (score 1):

Try this configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="True" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="True">
</serviceHostingEnvironment>-->
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="True">
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<services>
  <service name="WCFDemo.Service1">
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFDemo.IService1">
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://www.ekotri.com/Service1.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I have tested it on default WCF application project from visual studio and did not have any problems.

Comment: Nope bro its not working....   i got this error on trying your suggestions

The contract name 'IMetadataExchange' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service Service1.  Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the configuration file or to the ServiceHost directly to enable support for this contract.

Comment: Are you sure that service at `http://www.ekotri.com/Service1.svc` is the service implementing **Iservice.cs** that you mention in the question? When I access `http://www.ekotri.com/Service1.svc?wsdl` there is no **Authenticate** method. Or am I missing something? Also, whatever url I try I get **endpoint not found**. I think that we are debugging wrong service.

Comment: http://
www.ekotri.com/
Service1.svc/Data?Id〓2

try this one out... its working, which is in same service class... but not the authenticate method...

Comment: Have you removed listenUri attribute from rest endpoint binding? Also could you please enable help page for webhttp in **restfulBehavior** like `<webHttp helpEnabled="true" />`? And paste definition of your service class.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your interface like this

```
[OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Login/{inst}/{user}/{pwd}",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string Authenticate(string inst, string user, string pwd);
```

Put this configuration,

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="customBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="asmx" name="WCFDemo.Service1">
    <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="httpEndPoint" contract="WCFDemo.IService1"/>
    <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" name="webEndPoint" contract="WebApplication1.IService"/>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
            <webHttp />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="asmx">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

What url are you using when you attempt to hit your login method?

According to your service file, the url template you are using is

```
Login?InstId={inst}&UserId={user}&pwd={pwd}
```

Further in your config file you are binding it to a specific domain/url path

```
<endpoint address="http://www.ekotri.com/Service1.svc" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" listenUri="/" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WCFDemo.IService1">
```

Based on these two pieces of information, the expected access path would be

```
http://www.ekotri.com/Service1.svc/Login?InstId={inst}&UserId={user}&pwd={pwd}
```

If I take that template url and plug in some fake values..

[Service Action URL](http://www.ekotri.com/Service1.svc/Login?InstId=1&UserId=foo&pwd=bar)

This url returns "False" which is expected.

Comment: Yup it is returning true and false because i solved the error 4 days back. and hence you are getting desired output.

Comment: @shakil08it051 Update your question to indicate you fixed it or answer it yourself to close this question out